# How to make a keyboard with Android SDK 30?

Tags: android, keyboard

The playstore dictates we need to use 30 or higher for the SDK. However KeyboardView is deprecated. What do we use instead?
Are there any examples one can reference?

Comment: KeyboardView has nothing to do with making a keyboard.  No serious keyboard uses it.  Making a keyboard is all about creating an InputMethodService.  The UI of a keyboard can be anything you want.

Comment: BTW, the reason KeyboardView was deprecated was that it wasn't used by any real keyboard, and it wasn't worth maintaining as part of the framework.  Too niche of a usecase.  But it won't be going away anytime soon so you could use it.  And if you really need to you could even grab it from the AOSP and keep it updated as Android changes.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265148/how-to-properly-copy-deprecated-keyboardview-java-and-keyboard-java-to-android-p